# Sorting a date in Grid View

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have given the sorting option to all the columns in grid view. Sorting is not working for my date column alone. I am using itemTemplate and date as Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Effective_Date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"). code behind code is as below

```
    protected void ProductSearchResultGridView_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable sortTable = (DataTable)Session[SVDB_Resources.SearchResultGridSession];

        if (sortTable != null)
        {
            DataView sortedView = new DataView(sortTable);
            sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirectionString(e.SortExpression);               
            ProductSearchResultGridView.DataSource = sortedView;
            Session["SortedView"] = sortedView;
            ProductSearchResultGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tagged as Winforms? Sure?

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the string type - Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Effective_Date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") this will return string only. Try to use datetime like Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Effective_Date"))